# parent correlation id in message with rabbit queue and open telemetry

Tags: c#, message-queue, rabbitmq

I have a rabbit queue that I use to communicate between applications.
I have a chain of three message.

1. App 1 generate and push a message in rabbit(message 1)
2. App 2 catch the message and generate another message(message 2)
3. App 3 consume the message 2 and generate message 3

I have in each message

1. Correlation Id, is unique for each message
2. Parent correlation Id

I have two choices for Parent correlation Id in the message 3

1. Parent correlation in the message 3 is the correlation Id of message 1
2. Parent correlation in then message 3 is the correlation Id of message 2

In order to use Open Telemetry (in the future) it's better the first choice or the second?